# Plot different variables on different graphs on top of each other

Tags: r, plot, facet-wrap

I have 3 different variables (A, B, C) to be plotted on 3 graphs on top of each other(as they have different axis). My output has a lot of space between graphs and I would like to reduce that space and have an only X-Axis at the bottom and wider graph y-limits on all.

I have also read maybe facet_wrap is a better way of plotting multiple graphs? Could you please give me advice on what is best to do? Thanks

My data:

```
Location = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
A = c(1.16, 0.96, 0.67,0.78, 0.55, 0.3,0.26)
B = c(6.51, 4.98, 2.85, 3.19, 3.60, 10.82, 8.60)
C = c(75.45, 86.66, 103.36, NA, 107.53, NA, 128.49)

df = data.frame(Location, A, B, C)
```

My code:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))

plot(A, type = "l", col = "red", ylab = "A", main="Title", xlab = NULL)
plot(B, type = "l", col = "Blue", ylab = "B", xlab = NULL)
plot(C, type = "p", pch= 19, col = "Blue", ylab = "C", xlab = Location)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a slightly different way of doing it by reshaping your dataframe using `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% pivot_longer(.,-Location, names_to = "var",values_to = "val") %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Location, y = val, group = var, color = var))+
  geom_line()+
  ylab("")+
  facet_wrap(.~var, strip.position = "left", ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

**EDIT: Changing the scale of only facet**

To change the scale of only the B facet in order the y values ranged from 0 to 40, you can't use `scale_y_continuous` because it will apply on all facets.

But what you can do is to add two points in your dataframe with a value of 0 and 40 for the group B in order to force `ggplot` to plot in the full range. Then, you can pass the color of this part to transparent to (visually) remove them from the plot:

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(.,-Location, names_to = "var",values_to = "val") %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
  mutate(NewVar = var) %>%
  add_row(., Location = c(1,1),
          var = c("B","B"),
          val = c(0,40),
          NewVar = c("Out","Out")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Location, y = val, group = NewVar, color = NewVar))+
  geom_line()+
  ylab("")+
  facet_wrap(.~var, strip.position = "left", ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red","green","blue","transparent"), breaks = c("A","B","C"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However I get the Error...could not find function "pivot_longer". I have updated the library(tidyr) but seems to not to work. Is this a new function of the library?

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to load `tidyr` package before using `pivot_longer` function. If you don't have install `tidyr`, you can install it by doing `install,packages("tidyr")`

Comment: Apologies, re-initiating R worked as tidyr was already installed. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be possible to determine the y axis of the B variable ONLY within the code?  something such as scale_y_continuous(limits = [0,40]) ?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you a trick for doing it. Hope it satisfy you.

Comment: Hey @dc37 is it possible to rotate the y-title 90 degrees?  This changes the actual axis and I don't want that: theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))

Comment: I would like to rotate the A, B, C labels (are they called y titles?)

Comment: They are `strip.text.y`, try to add this in `theme` function: `strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180)`

Comment: Another question, @dc37 would it be possible to merge this graph https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856799/label-datapoints-in-a-map-in-r on top of the ones we have on this post, labelled as (1)coordinates, (2) A, (3) B. (4) C.

Comment: Take a look at `gridExtra` or `ggarrange` packages ;)

Answer (score 2):

here You have the x label "Location" just at the end

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))

plot(A, type = "l", col = "red", ylab = "A", main="Title", xlab = "")
plot(B, type = "l", col = "Blue", ylab = "B", xlab = "")
plot(C, type = "p", pch= 19, col = "Blue", ylab = "C", xlab = "Location")
```

Comment: SOrry, I means I would like to reduce the space between graphs, and remove the x axis labels so graphs are shown on top of each other with the only x-axis at the very bottom one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `facet_wrap`. I restructured your data slightly.

```
df <- data.frame(Location = rep(Location, 3), y = c(A,B,C), letter = rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 7))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Location, y = y, color = letter)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:7), labels = c(1:7)) +
  facet_wrap(~letter, nrow = 3, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "blue")) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan, this is very useful. Would it be possible for variable C to ignore the NA (missing values) and link the rest of the data points? Or just plot the points and no line?

Comment: You can remove the NAs from your df before plotting: df <- df[!is.na(df$y),] and this will connect the points